# How to get weapon skins for the items in inventory

Tags: steam-web-api

I am able to get items in inventory by comparing the getschema defindex and the getplayeritems defined. But all of them are just the base weapon models. How can I get the appropriate skins?

Comment: Can you give more details and show your code? [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)